# Vue i18n - saving locale to localStorage

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I have been able to setup i18n in my app (following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-vue-with-i18n).  Selecting the language works, however it is lost upon refresh.  How should the setting be saved?  Is this done with localStorage?  Thank you

```
<select v-model="$i18n.locale">
    <option
      v-for="(lang, i) in langs"
      :key="`lang-${i}`"
      :value="lang"
     >
     {{ lang }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

On select Language :
store locale on **localStorage**

```
    localStorage.setItem('lang',localeCode)
```

and on main.js at start of application

```
new VueI18n({
  locale: (localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'en'), // set default locale
  },
})
```

Comment: thanks - can you elaborate on the first part? my select is currently in the original post

Answer (score 0):

You could use Vuex to store a the locale selected and then watch that variable with Vue watch(){}